OBIEE 12.2.1.4 to OAS 6.4 exportarchive.sh Error
Background:
We are upgrading our Safety System (  Oracle Argus Safety System from  version 8.2.3.1 to 8.4.2).  Analytics application connected to Argus Safety System 8.2.3.1 is OBIEE 12.2.1.3.  Argus Safety 8.4.2 system supports only OAS 6.4 hence we have to upgrade and migrate OBIEE 12.2.1.3 to OAS 6.4.
Approach:

New OAS Instance of OAS: New Instance of OAS 6.4 was created in a separate server (Oracle Linux)

In Place Upgrade of 12.2.1.3 to 12.2.1.4 following guidance in the following article
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bi12214/lcm/OBIUP/GUID-93B3A0DC-7546-4ABB-946E-593B3AAE444D.htm#OBIUP-GUID-93B3A0DC-7546-4ABB-946E-593B3AAE444D

Out of Place Migration from 12.2.1.4 to OAS 6.4, When attempting this received error.  Following article was followed
https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/bi/analytics-server/migrate-upgrade-oas/migrating-oracle-business-intelligence-12c-or-previous-release-oracle-analytics-server.html#GUID-526D3344-6CE6-448B-8DC4-7D5CB2F40FE4


Issue:
When running ./exportarchive.sh ssi /opt/oracle/backup_dir/exportedarchive.sh give following error in log files
2
024-05-18T08:19:43.882+02:00] [bi] [WARNING] [] [oracle.bi.web.datasetsvc] [tid: 10] [ecid: 0000OyAMkL73BDYVLqINOA1aI4Xn000002,0] Could not create config from property file[[
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/oracle/middleware/user_projects/domains/bi/config/fmwconfig/biconfig/DSS/DatasetsvcConfig.properties (No such file or directory)

Troubleshooting Step:

I backed up domains folder before upgrading 12.2.1.3 to 12.1.2.4, I checked in backedup folder, the DatasetsvcConfig.properties is missing.
I checked in new OAS Installation also, this file is missing.
What is the use of this file, why it is missing/ why exportarchive.sh is looking for this file.

